# How to select the last one test without NA in r

Tags: r, select, na

My dataframe is similar like this:

```
Person  W.1   W.2   W.3   W.4   W.5   
1       62    57    52    59    NA
2       49    38    60    NA    NA
3       59    34    NA    NA    NA
```

Is there a way to select the first and last test without "NA". I have 300 data entries, and W.1 means the first test, W.2 means the second test, W.n means the nth test. I want to compare the score of the first test with the score of the last test. For example, I want to compare:

```
1    62 59
2    49 60
3    59 34
```

But different persons have different places having "NA", can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
> t(apply(d[-1],1,function(rw) rw[range(which(!is.na(rw)))]))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   62   59
[2,]   49   60
[3,]   59   34
```

where `d` is your data set.

How it works: for each row of `d` (rows are scanned using `apply(d[-1],1,...)`, where `d[-1]` excludes the first column), get the indices of non-NA test results (`which(!is.na(rw))`), then get the lowest and highest value of indices by using `range()`, and obtain the test scores that correspond to those indices (`rw[...]`). The final result is transposed using `t()`.

Note that this solution will work properly even in the case of NAs in the middle of the test scores, e.g. `c(NA, 57, NA, 52, NA)`.

Comment: I like your explanation. It helps me a lot. Thank you very much! @Marat Talipov

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible vectorized solution using `max.col` (I'm assuming that the first test is never `NA`, though it can be easily fixed if otherwise)

```
indx <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = "last"))
cbind(df[, 2], df[indx])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   62   59
# [2,]   49   60
# [3,]   59   34
```

Another similar solution is to use `rowSums`

```
cbind(df[, 2], df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), rowSums(!is.na(df)))])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   62   59
# [2,]   49   60
# [3,]   59   34
```